# az login error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: azure, powershell

I am getting the error `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)` after successfully running az login. This is because the computer in use is behind a proxy.

I have done some research and came across various links, such as this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541003/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-issue-using-azure-cli-on-windows), however I am not sure what I am missing. AZ cli was installed using chocolatey and not python. I had to create the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi` manually, after doing this I went onto portal.azure to come to export the cert into a pem file on the path above, then closed the powershell console and started a new one, ran `az login` same problem. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly here.

Comment: 1. Check this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=bash,bash2#work-behind-a-proxy) 2. `install pip install certifi` and install python like [this](https://i.imgur.com/XJCi3Rq.png) if not install  use `/Applications/Python\ 3.9/Install\ Certificates.command`

Comment: @Imran I got the error below `WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/certifi/` and the last one `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi`

Comment: It seems that you are facing an issue with installing the certifi package. Try [this](https://python-forum.io/thread-12634.html)