# Load CA Certificate to OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate

As we know while creating an `SSL` connection using openssl api's, we creates an `SSL_CTX` context object in which all certificates and keys are loaded.

To set up **Peer Verification**, we load the **CA Certificate** using `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` api (CA is stored in a file)

But now in my case CA is not in file, i have a `X509 *issuerCert`.
Now how to set this `issuerCert` in `SSL_CTX` object ?

I found this :-
[C++/OpenSSL: Use root CA from buffer rather than file (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052563/c-openssl-use-root-ca-from-buffer-rather-than-file-ssl-ctx-load-verify-locat)

In above solution we are creating an `X509_STORE *` using `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store` and finally add the `X509 *issuerCert` in it.

Now i am confused here, since adding this cert to `X509_STORE *` add it in store only, how that cert information will be linked to `SSL_CTX` ?

Since ultimately we pass `SSL_CTX` to `SSL_connect` where all verification(handshaking) happens behind the scenes. So how that CA cert info
will reach to `SSL_connect` when using `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store` instead of
`SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In above solution we are creating an X509_STORE * using
>   SSL_CTX_get_cert_store and finally add the X509 *issuerCert in it.

You are not "creating" the cert store using `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store`. You are getting a pointer to the cert store which is part of the SSL_CTX. Any updates to the cert store will be reflected in the SSL_CTX. Note, that the API has the following syntax, which takes the SSL_CTX as an argument:

```
X509_STORE *SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(const SSL_CTX *ctx);
```

Comment: Thanx. Please see if you can help me here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655411/how-to-convert-x509-certificate-to-stack-ofx509-name/38662865#38662865)