# How to Convert `X509 *`Certificate to `STACK_OF(X509_NAME)`

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

How to Convert `X509 *`Certificate to `STACK_OF(X509_NAME)`

Need to pass this `STACK_OF(X509_NAME)` to openssl api `ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i have tried so many openssl api's but none of it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pass `STACK_OF(X509_NAME)` to `ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert`...

You have not given us much to work with. Its not clear what your problem is, so its hard to say what you should be doing differently.

Start tracing OpenSSL's code in `<openssl src dir>/ssl/s3_clnt.c`:

```
int ssl_do_client_cert_cb(SSL *s, X509 **px509, EVP_PKEY **ppkey)
{
    int i = 0;
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
    if (s->ctx->client_cert_engine) {
        i = ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert(s->ctx->client_cert_engine, s,
                                        SSL_get_client_CA_list(s),
                                        px509, ppkey, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (i != 0)
            return i;
    }
#endif
    if (s->ctx->client_cert_cb)
        i = s->ctx->client_cert_cb(s, px509, ppkey);
    return i;
}
```

As you can see, it takes a stack of `X509`, not `X509_NAME`. I've never spent any significant time working with the ENGINE code, so I'm not sure what happens next.

You might also be interested in [STACK API](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/STACK_API) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Finally, there are some other hits you may b interested in. I was kind of surprised to see there were *no* hits in one of the apps.

```
$ grep -IR ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert *
crypto/engine/eng_err.c:     "ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert"},
crypto/engine/eng_pkey.c:int ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert(ENGINE *e, SSL *s,
crypto/engine/engine.h:int ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert(ENGINE *e, SSL *s,
ssl/s3_clnt.c:        i = ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert(s->ctx->client_cert_engine, s,
util/libeay.num:ENGINE_load_ssl_client_cert             4046    EXIST::FUNCTION:ENGINE
```