# How to open ssl socket using certificate stored in string variables in python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, certificate

In Python, ssl.wrap_socket can read certificates from files, ssl.wrap_socket require the certificate as a file path.

How can I start an SSL connection using a certificate read from string variables?

My host environment does not allow write to files, and tempfile module is not functional
I'm using Python 2.7.
I store the certificate inside MySQL and read as a string.

Edit:
I gave up, this is basically require implement ssl by pure python code, this is beyond my current knowledge.

Comment: Surely your host environment allows you to store SSL certificates, somehow? even if they want to supply them themselves.

Comment: I saved the certificate data in mysql. my code need a ssl socket to another host to retrieve data. I read the certificate from database, but don't know how to create the ssl wrap.

Comment: Looking at the source, ssl.wrap_socket calls directly into the native code (openssl) function  SSL_CTX_use_cert_chain_file which requires a path to a file, so what you are trying to do is not possible.

You need to write the cert to a file for this to work.

Comment: You'd need to write a **temporal file**, **pass it to OpenSSL** and **remove** it in the **smallest possible time**, to minimize the security risk. `os.tmpnam()` will return a random filepath.

Comment: Perhaps it is practical to enter all possible CA certificates to a static file, direct SSL to use that file and check what CA was verified against after the connection is established?

Comment: I have similar issue when I was developing backend for ios application. I didn't try yet - but maybe you can switch to pyOpenSSL instead of native ssl. For my case I would try this library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns-client/0.2.1 instead of this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns/2.0.1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Looking at the source, ssl.wrap_socket calls directly into the native code (openssl) function  SSL_CTX_use_cert_chain_file which requires a path to a file, so what you are trying to do is not possible.

For reference:

In ssl/**init**.py we see:

```
def wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None,
                server_side=False, cert_reqs=CERT_NONE,
                ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv23, ca_certs=None,
                do_handshake_on_connect=True):

    return SSLSocket(sock, keyfile=keyfile, certfile=certfile,
                   server_side=server_side, cert_reqs=cert_reqs,
                   ssl_version=ssl_version, ca_certs=ca_certs,
                   do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect)
```

Points us to the SSLSocket constructor (which is in the same file) and we see the following happen:

```
self._sslobj = _ssl2.sslwrap(self._sock, server_side,
                                     keyfile, certfile,
                                     cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs)
```

_ssl2 is implemented in C (_ssl2.c)

Looking at the sslwrap function, we see it's creating a new object:

```
    return (PyObject *) newPySSLObject(Sock, key_file, cert_file,
                                       server_side, verification_mode,
                                       protocol, cacerts_file);
```

Looking at the constructor for that object, we eventually see:

```
            ret = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(self->ctx,
                                                     cert_file);
```

That function is defined in openssl, so now we need to switch to that codebase.

In ssl/ssl_rsa.c we eventually find in the function:

```
BIO_read_filename(in,file)
```

If you dig far enough into the BIO code (part of openssl) you'll eventually come to a normal fopen():

```
fp=fopen(ptr,p);
```

So it looks like as it's currently written. It must be in a file openable by C's fopen().

Also, since python's ssl library so quickly jumps into C, I don't see a immediately obvious place to monkeypatch in a workaround either.

Comment: I have java client and python server. I prepared java keystore, extracted keys and certificate from it as pem files and specified them for `wrap_socket()` in python server. Now I am able to read key and certificate strings directly from keystore using `pyjks` as a string. Cant I use those key and certificate strings for preparing ssl socket in some way?

Comment: @domenukk Can you please confirm if it is not really possible to do what I have explained in above comment?

Comment: Yes I can confirm it's not possible. You will need to store them to disk or some sort of tmpfs or pseudo filesystem.

Comment: dima's suggestion below about using a pure-python crypto library like M2 is probably the best solution to this issue.

Comment: That's a little unfortunate since so many libraries depends on SSLContext, not socket as their input. If SSLContext can't take a string, if means fixes must be made in many codebases. Sad trombone.

Answer (score 8):

From Python 3.4, you can use SSLContext#load_verify_locations:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_verify_locations(cadata=cert)  # Where cert is str.
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations

Comment: This also appears to work in Python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context

Comment: Shouldn't this be the answer to this question?

Comment: @R.Navega No.  This is for the CA trust store, not for a server or client cert and private key as the questions asks for.

Comment: @GaryvanderMerwe I've reread the question and I still think it's asking about "opening an SSL socket using a (single) certificate object stored in a string variable". I could not find a mention for a cert and private key, and if I'm not mistaken can't they both be in the same certificate file? As the docs say, `an ASCII string of one or more PEM-encoded certificates`

Answer (score 5):

Quick look though the ssl module source confirms what you want is not supported by the API:
http://code.google.com/codesearch#2T6lfGELm_A/trunk/Modules/_ssl.c&q=sslwrap&type=cs

Which is not to say it is impossible, you could create a named pipe, feed one end from Python and give the filename to the ssl module.

For simpler, less secure use, dump cert from memory to mkstemp()'d file.

You could even mount FUSE volume and intercept file callback.

Finally, use ctypes to hack at ssl context at runtime and load cert/ket from a buffer following the C recipe [Read certificate files from memory instead of a file using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810058/read-certificate-files-from-memory-instead-of-file-openssl) Things like these have been done before, but it's not for the faintest of heart.

It looks like you are trying to get out of e.g. app engine "jail," perhaps it is just not possible?

If you are not picky on ssl implementation, you can use M2Crypto, TLS Lite, pyOpenSSL or something else. The earlier is pure python, you can definitely hack it to use in-memory certificates/keys.

Comment: The named pipe is basically a temp file, isn't it?
Very good ideas though.
I think using M2Crypto or something similar will be the best approach then.

Comment: yes creating named pipe requires write permission on filesystem

Comment: Even after having hooked into `load_verify_locations` of `ssl._ssl._SSLContext` using ctypes hackery, all that function gets is a `ssl.SSLContext` object  and it's a mystery to me how to use that to access the right memory location that was allocated for the underlying `PySSLContext` parent class, so that I can retrieve the pointer to its `ctx` member of type `SL_CTX *`. Does anybody have any (literal) pointers?

Comment: In case anybody else is interested in how to pull this off, I made this problem into a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762019

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.4 added support for a `cdata` parameter to load certificates from a string. From https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations:

"The cadata object, if present, is either an ASCII string of one or more PEM-encoded certificates or a bytes-like object of DER-encoded certificates. Like with capath extra lines around PEM-encoded certificates are ignored but at least one certificate must be present".

Comment: This is for the CA trust store, not for a server or client cert and private key as the questions asks for.

Answer (score -3):

You can treat strings like files with [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html).

Comment: StringIO is not working under ssl.wrap_socket, that require a string as file path.

Exception:
TypeError('must be string or None, not instance',)
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/www/htdocs/705/pty/1/pty.py", line 23, in connect
    self.push.connect(self.gateway)
  File "/usr/local/sae/python/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 331, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/local/sae/python/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 314, in _real_connect
    self.ca_certs, self.ciphers)
TypeError: must be string or None, not instance

Comment: So it takes a file path and not a file object