# Is there a way to create an encrypted memory block hosting a filesystem for a userland application?

Tags: python, encryption, filesystems, python-requests, pyopenssl

I am dealing with some p12 certificates that I need to parse and pass to the python requests module.  As they cannot take a p12 directly, I am using pyopenssl to parse them into certificates and keys.

But because requests cert parameter cannot accept anothing other than a path to a file ( see reference 1 ), I need to write these decrypted values to disk.

This got me thinking.  Is there some way for a ring 3 ( user land ) application to create an encrypted memory block ( be it in memory or on disk ) and lay down a fileystem that is solely accessible to the application, for it to write temporary files to.  Theoretically this is possible, however I was just curious if anyone knew of any existing software/librariers/modules that could achieve this.

reference 1: [How to open ssl socket using certificate stored in string variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336239/how-to-open-ssl-socket-using-certificate-stored-in-string-variables-in-python)

Comment: On linux, look at systemd and PrivateTmp. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Comment: I would never use systemd.  It is malware.  Also, systemd's solution appears to only be a namespace isolation.  Not encryption at rest.

Comment: Tempted to just use a packer.  And just let it handle the crypto bit.

Comment: Have you looked into the [FUSE filesystem](https://www.google.com/search?q=FUSE+filesystem)? To restrict access to just your application, then you probably need a PaX kernel or SELinux. But its just a guess since I have not used FUSE and I rarely use SELinux.

Comment: I considered fuse... not sure how you'd app restrict it.  SELinux / Apparmor seems an approach but that's more namespacing / chroot style solutions.  I'd rather have something with a better isolation mechanism.  I figure worst case scenario I pack it like it's malware.