# How to make secure connection with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, https

I'm using python3. i need to use certificates file to make secure connection.
In this case, i used Httpsconnection class from http.client...
this class get certs file path and use it. like this:

```
 import http.client
 client=http.client.HTTPSConnection\
 ("epp.nic.ir",key_file="filepath\\nic.pem",cert_file="filepath\\nic.crt")
```

As you see, this class get path of files and works correctly.
But I need to give contents of these files. Because I want to put contents of crt file and pem file into DB. the reason is that maybe files path changes...
so i tried this:

```
import http.client
import base64

cert = b'''
content of cert file
'''
pem = b'''
content of pem file
'''
client=http.client.HTTPSConnection("epp.nic.ir" ,pem, cert)
```

as expected, i got this error:

```
TypeError: certfile should be a valid filesystem path
```

is there any way to make this class to get content of file instead of file path ?!
Or Is it possible to make changes in source codes of http for this purpose ?!

Comment: http.client (and some other ssl-related modules) API seems not supporting this feature. I found this discussion which is about adding such a feature to ssl module: https://bugs.python.org/issue16487

This SO thread may also give some idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336239/how-to-open-ssl-socket-using-certificate-stored-in-string-variables-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to modify Python source code, but it is not the recommended way as it definitely brings about portability, maintainability and other issues.

- Consider you want to update Python version, you have to apply your modification each time you update it.
- Consider you want to run your code in another machine, again the same problem.

Instead of modifying the source code, there is a better and preferrable way: extending the API.

You can subclass the existing `HTTPSConnection` class and override its constructor method by your own implementation.

There are plenty of ways to achieve what you need.

Here is a possible solution with subclassing:

```
import http.client
import tempfile

class MyHTTPSConnection(http.client.HTTPSConnection):
    """HTTPSConnection with key and cert files passed as contents rather than file names"""

    def __init__(self, host, key_content=None, cert_content=None, **kwargs):
        # additional parameters are also optional so that
        # so that this class can be used with or without cert/key files
        # as a replacement of standard HTTPSConnection
        self.key_file = None
        self.cert_file = None

        # here we write the content of cert & pem into a temporary file
        # delete=False keeps the file in the file system
        # but, this time we need to remove it manually when we are done
        if key_content:
            self.key_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
            self.key_file.write(key_content)
            self.key_file.close()
            # NamedTemporaryFile object provides 'name' attribute
            # which is a valid file name in the file system
            # so we can use those file names to initiate the actual HTTPSConnection
            kwargs['key_file'] = self.key_file.name

        # same as above but this time for cert content and cert file
        if cert_content:
            self.cert_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
            self.cert_file.write(cert_content)
            self.cert_file.close()
            kwargs['cert_file'] = self.cert_file.name


        # initialize super class with host and keyword arguments
        super().__init__(host, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        # remove temp files from the file system
        # you need to decide when to call this method
        os.unlink(self.cert_file.name)
        os.unlink(self.pem_file.name)

host = "epp.nic.ir"
key_content = b'''content of key file'''
cert_content = b'''content of cert file'''

client = MyHTTPSConnection(host, key_content=key_content, cert_content=cert_content)
# ...
```