# How to read certificate chain in DER format in openssl, or alternative to PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio to read from DER object?

Tags: c, openssl, certificate

This question is followup on an another question:-
[Read certificate files from memory instead of a file using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810058/read-certificate-files-from-memory-instead-of-file-openssl/32250441#32250441)

In the above thread, there was a solution by using PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio to get a stack of (X509_INFO) looking for similar api if i have to read it from a DER object.

Comment: From what i understand a certificate chain file CANNOT be represented as a single DER object and hence there are no functions like d2i_X509_INFO_read_bio where it takes a DER formatted certificate chain file.

Comment: A certificate chain can indeed be represented as a single DER object using the PKCS#7 format.