# Retrieving address of native base class with ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, cpython, monkeypatching, pyopenssl

I want to be able to pass a certificate to Python's ssl library without requiring a temporary file. It seems that the Python ssl module [cannot do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336239).

To work around this problem I want to retrieve the underlying `SSL_CTX` struct stored in the `ssl._ssl._SSLContext` class from the native `_ssl` module. Using ctypes I could then manually call the respective `SSL_CTX_*` functions from libssl with that context. How to do that in C is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810058) and I would do the same thing via ctypes.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck at the point where I managed to hook into the `load_verify_locations` function from `ssl._ssl._SSLContext` but seem to be unable to get the right memory address of the instance of the `ssl._ssl._SSLContext` struct. All the `load_verify_locations` function is seeing is the parent `ssl.SSLContext` object.

My question is, how do I get from an instance of a `ssl.SSLContext` object to the memory of the native base class `ssl._ssl._SSLContext`? If I would have that, I could easily access its `ctx` member.

Here is my code so far. Credits for how to monkeypatch a native Python module go to [the forbidden fruit project by  Lincoln Clarete](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit)

```
Py_ssize_t = hasattr(ctypes.pythonapi, 'Py_InitModule4_64') and ctypes.c_int64 or ctypes.c_int

class PyObject(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

PyObject._fields_ = [
    ('ob_refcnt', Py_ssize_t),
    ('ob_type', ctypes.POINTER(PyObject)),
]

class SlotsProxy(PyObject):
    _fields_ = [('dict', ctypes.POINTER(PyObject))]

class PySSLContext(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

PySSLContext._fields_ = [
        ('ob_refcnt', Py_ssize_t),
        ('ob_type', ctypes.POINTER(PySSLContext)),
        ('ctx', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ]

name = ssl._ssl._SSLContext.__name__
target = ssl._ssl._SSLContext.__dict__
proxy_dict = SlotsProxy.from_address(id(target))
namespace = {}
ctypes.pythonapi.PyDict_SetItem(
        ctypes.py_object(namespace),
        ctypes.py_object(name),
        proxy_dict.dict,
)
patchable = namespace[name]

old_value = patchable["load_verify_locations"]

libssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libssl.so.1.0.0")
libssl.SSL_CTX_set_verify.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p)
libssl.SSL_CTX_get_verify_mode.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,)

def load_verify_locations(self, cafile, capath, cadata):
    print(self)
    print(self.verify_mode)
    addr = PySSLContext.from_address(id(self)).ctx
    libssl.SSL_CTX_set_verify(addr, 1337, None)
    print(libssl.SSL_CTX_get_verify_mode(addr))
    print(self.verify_mode)
    return old_value(self, cafile, capath, cadata)

patchable["load_verify_locations"] = load_verify_locations

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
```

The output is:

```
<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x7f4b81304ba8>
2
1337
2
```

This suggests, that whatever I'm changing is not the ssl context that Python knows about but some other random memory location.

To try out the code from above, you have to run a https server. Generate a self-signed SSL certificate using:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -subj '/CN=localhost' -nodes
```

And start a server using the following code:

```
import http.server, http.server
import ssl
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='cert.pem', keyfile='key.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And then add the following line to the end of my example code above:

```
urllib.request.urlopen("https://localhost:4443", context=context)
```

Comment: How are you calling this code? When I run your code it just exits

Comment: @TarunLalwani you need to pass the context to urllib to open some URL with it. Let me amend the question.

Comment: For me the method doesn't get called at all? The failure happens in `do_handshake` which actually happens in the SSL c code, `ssl.py`, `self._sslobj.do_handshake()` line

Comment: How about another approach that is creating named pipe, which should be read as file? So no temporary file is created and SSL API is maintained? I can try to do some demo usage if you want.

Comment: @josch, any updates on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual `SSLContext` answer forthcoming, the assumption is no longer correct.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations

There's a 3rd argument, `cadata`

> The cadata object, if present, is either an ASCII string of one or
>   more PEM-encoded certificates or a bytes-like object of DER-encoded
>   certificates.

Apparently that's the case since Python 3.4

#### Getting the underlying PyObject context

This one's easy, `ssl.SSLContext` inherits from `_ssl._SSLContext` which in Python data model means that there's just one object at one memory address.

Therefore, `ssl.SSLContext().load_verify_locations(...)` will actually call:

```
ctx = \
ssl.SSLContext.__new__(<type ssl.SSLContext>, ...)  # which calls
    self = _ssl._SSLContext.__new__(<type ssl.SSLContext>, ...)  # which calls
        <type ssl.SSLContext>->tp_alloc()  # which understands inheritance
        self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(...)  # _ssl fields
    self.set_ciphers(...)  # ssl fields
    return self

_ssl._SSLContext.load_verify_locations(ctx, ...)`.
```

The C implementation will get an object of seemingly wrong type, but that's OK because all the expected fields are there, as it was allocated by generic `type->tp_alloc` and fields were filled in first by `_ssl._SSLContext` and then by `ssl.SSLContext`.

Here's a demonstration (tedious details omitted):

```
# _parent.c
typedef struct {
  PyObject_HEAD
} PyParent;

static PyObject* parent_new(PyTypeObject* type, PyObject* args,
                            PyObject* kwargs) {
  PyParent* self = (PyParent*)type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
  printf("Created parent %ld\n", (long)self);
  return (PyObject*)self;
}

# child.py
class Child(_parent.Parent):
    def foo(self):
        print(id(self))

c1 = Child()
print("Created child:", id(c1))

# prints:
Created parent 139990593076080
Created child: 139990593076080
```

#### Getting the underlying OpenSSL context

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    <details skipped>
} PySSLContext;
```

Thus, `ctx` is at a known offset, which is:

```
PyObject_HEAD
This is a macro which expands to the declarations of the fields of the PyObject type; it is used when declaring new types which represent objects without a varying length. The specific fields it expands to depend on the definition of Py_TRACE_REFS. By default, that macro is not defined, and PyObject_HEAD expands to:

Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
PyTypeObject *ob_type;

When Py_TRACE_REFS is defined, it expands to:

PyObject *_ob_next, *_ob_prev;
Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
PyTypeObject *ob_type;
```

Thus, in a production (non-debug) build, and taking natural alignment into consideration, `PySSLContext` becomes:

```
struct {
    void*;
    void*;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    ...
}
```

Therefore:

```
_ctx = _ssl._SSLContext(2)
c_ctx = ctypes.cast(id(_ctx), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
c_ctx[:3]
[1, 140486908969728, 94916219331584]
# refcnt,      type,          C ctx
```

#### Putting it all together

```
import ssl
import socket
import ctypes
import pytest


def contact_github(cafile=""):
    ctx = ssl.SSLContext()
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.VerifyMode.CERT_REQUIRED

    # ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile, "empty", None) done via ctypes
    ssl_ctx = ctypes.cast(id(ctx), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))[2]
    cssl = ctypes.CDLL("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1")
    cssl.SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]
    assert cssl.SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ssl_ctx, cafile.encode("utf-8"), b"empty")

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("github.com", 443))

    ss = ctx.wrap_socket(s)
    ss.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n")
    print(ss.recv(1024))


def test_wrong_cert():
    with pytest.raises(ssl.SSLError):
        contact_github(cafile="bad-cert.pem")


def test_correct_cert():
    contact_github(cafile="good-cert.pem")
```